# Simpleform with two models not nested but linked, failing to submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

For the moment I've got two models in my app.

```
class Budget < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project
end
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :budget
end
```

So each project has a budget, but a budget could be used later for different class, so it's not especially a "child" of a project.

I tried differents things for the form, here is the one that works the most for the moment :

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<%= f.input :name %>
  <%= simple_fields_for @budget do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.input :amount %>
  <% end %>
<%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

I tried to replace simple_fields_for by simpleform_for but when I'm doing so when I click "Submit" button, nothing happens.
With that version when I click Submit there is this error :

```
"undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass"
```

I don't really understand how I'm not working on an existing class here.

Here's my conroller

```
def create
respond_to do |format|
  @budget = Budget.new(params.require("budget").permit(:amount))
  if @budget.save # If budget is saved
    puts "Budget successfuly created"
    @project.budget = @budget
    if @project.save
      puts "project successfuly created"
    else
      puts "Unable to create project"
      format.html { render :new, notice: 'Project went wrong' }
    end
    format.html { redirect_to projects_path, notice: 'Success' }
  else # If budget isn't saved
    puts "Unable to create budget"
    format.json { render json: @budget.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.html { render :new, notice: 'Budget went wrong' }
  end
end
```

I'm searching for good practice concerning simpleform and rails coding, but I can't really find something that is related to my case, or at least I can't recognize what documentation relates to my case.

PS : In my rails console, I've got that output :
    Unable to create budget

Comment: Where do you have the method `model_name`?

Comment: The controller you included is Budgets or Projects? The view is Budgets or Projects? Can you also put the new method that displays this view?

Comment: @PeterHøjlundAndersen : nowhere, I think it's a rails or active_record method

@ Pablo : The controller is from Project, so as the view, in fact for budget there is juste the "create" route, and a "create" method in it's controller that just contains "Budget.new"

Comment: EDIT : At the end nested models seems more appropriate, so there will be ITEM_A's budget, ITEM_B's budget, etc... I think I can make a route for every item, it shouldn't be a problem. So now in my view there is :
    <%= simple_form_for [@project, @budget] do |f| %>

Issues I declared in my original post are gone, now I face this one : I want to create budget and project in the same form so in the same time, but I can't create a budget if not in a project, and I can't create a project if it don't has a budget, so I'm stuck here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is a bit hacky. I would look into the default [generated create method by the scaffold generater](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/getting_started.html#creating-new-posts)

To get a good idea of how you could clean it up. That would mean a better chance for debugging.

---

#### Nested params

One thing i do see is, that something is wrong in your param call.

`@budget = Budget.new(params.require("budget").permit(:amount))`

This is like saying: *Find the param 'amount' for budget.*

**But your params are generated differently by your form:**

You have a simple form for `@projects` with a simple field for `@budget`.

Therefore your params will be nested like this:

`params[:project][:budget]`

Hope it helps.

---

By the way: Do you have a before_action to set `@project`?

Or else that would return `nil` on line 6 in your controller.

Comment: I don't set any before_action for project, I think it's a good hint I will test that first.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: Kind of, for the moment it work enough for my needs, but don't work as expected. I need to read more doc.
And I redefine the problem also, at the end I'm using nested models